# ANSI control sequence: after setting line home and limit, how should cursor movements behave? which coordinates to use?

Tags: ansi-escape

Context:
I'm working on a device which inserted between an electronic typewriter's controller and its keyboard turns it into a serial printer/terminal.
I want it to support some of the control sequences from ECMA-48 / ISO-6429 / ANSI X3.64. (also known as ANSI escape code)

I'm having some uncertainty if I'm understanding correctly the standard, so I would like to ask to know how it should be.
It's related to the commands SLH - SET LINE HOME and SLL - SET LINE LIMIT.

For example I could have the situation that I have 1/12 inch wide characters, I want a left margin of 1 inch, and 80 columns of text.
Then I would set page home to 13 and page limit to 92.
(since character positions are counted from 1, home is the first position, limit is the last)
So far ok.

But when I already have set the home, than how should the functions:
CHA - CURSOR CHARACTER ABSOLUTE
CUP - CURSOR POSITION
HPA - CHARACTER POSITION ABSOLUTE
CPR - ACTIVE POSITION REPORT
and others related to the cursor position work?

Should they use coordinates relative to to the actual edge, or to the home position.
So in my above example if I wanted to move to column 2 of the text print area (home being 13), I should use coordinate 2 or 14?
(similarly for vertical position and page home & limit)

My understanding is that these control sequences still use the absolute coordinates.
so in my example I would have to use coordinate 14.

0. Is this correct?

And if it is correct, this raises some additional problems:

1. I would have to know where the margins are to know which horizontal and vertical offset to use when moving the cursor to absolute positions.
   If a program sets the margins first, then no problem, but I a program connects to the device and does not change the margins then it does not know the offset.
   (There is a way, it could send a carriage return to move to the home position and then request the ACTIVE POSITION REPORT to discover the left margin position, but it does not look like a nice solution)
2. What should my device do if it is requested to move to a position outside the defined home and limit?
   The standard says that beyond these limits no implicit movement should happen, but this is explicit movement.
   If it receives a command to move to position 1 when the home is 13 what should it do? Move to 1? Move to 13? ignore?
   When it is at position 15, home is at 13 and receives command to move cursor left by 4 positions should it move by 4 to 11? move by 2 to 13? ignore?

Another problem I see is that there is a command to set page home, and page limit, but not total page height.
It is only possible to select predefined formats by PFS - PAGE FORMAT SELECTION.
But I don't see a way to select any other height.

If I want to use continuous paper with 12 inch long pages (72 lines of text at 1/6 inch line height) connected together into a long tape then I see no way to define that height so that my device can correctly keep track of its positions on the following pages. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: It depends: VT100s have *origin mode*, but that's not specified in ECMA-48.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I had to find the answers by myself.

question 0:
Yes, it appears, that the coordinates should still be absolute.
he standard says about character positions in a line and line positions in a page and these are specified in the beginning of the document and nowhere at all is said about it being relative. Looks like the only role of line home and limit is the place where CR (and some others) returns to, and limit of where implicit movement (like advancing forward after printing a character) can go, similar for page home and page limit.

question 1:
There is no easy way for a program to recognise where the home and limit positions are. As I mentioned, requesting ACTIVE POSITION REPORT can help if this is implemented. (my devece does not support it yet).
Anyway, many programs don't recognise the concept of line home, and assume that normal character positions start from 1.
My solution to this is that after power on, the line home IS exactly at position 1, and if you want something else, you have to specify it.
This way a program can safely make this assumption.
(However after the PFS - PAGE FORMAT SELECTION command I do set the line home to 1 inch as this is what the standard proposes)

question 2:
As above, the home and limit are only a margin for implicit movements. So the cursor movement commands will move outside these limits with no problem. Only the actual page size will limit them.

question 3:
(but I didn't give it a number when asked)
DTA - DIMENSION TEXT AREA is the command for this purpose. It specifies the size of the text area limited by the actual page size, not by the home and limit positions.